# Why casting IQueryable to .toList() include data to object DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, extension-methods

I have a code example that is using entity-framework

This one is working:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BlogContext dbContext = new BlogContext();
        dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags).ToList();
        return View(dbContext.Posts.ToList());
    }
```

and this one is not:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BlogContext dbContext = new BlogContext();
        dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags);
        return View(dbContext.Posts.ToList());
    }
```

So I do not understand, why only casting to `List` is enough to include tags from the model (`List<Tags>`), I would understand if it would be like this, which is fine too (and I am using that! Question is not about code formating!):

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BlogContext dbContext = new BlogContext();
        var model=dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

but it does not need to be. So my question is:
**Why casting IQueryable to toList is including data to object `dbContext`?** I know that in entity-framework we are working with extensions but as far as I remember extensions return values not assign one to an object.

This is my partial view that is crashing:

```
@using BlogWeb.Models
@model Post


    <h1>@Model.Title</h1>
    <p class="lead">
        by <a href="#">1234</a>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p>@Model.Created</p>
    <p class="lead">
        @Model.Body
    </p>
    @Html.Partial("_Tags", Model.Tags) -<< this is what is throwing error
    <hr>
```

And this is a partial tag view

```
@using BlogWeb.Models
@model List<Tag>
@foreach (Tag tag in Model)
{
    @Html.Label('#' + tag.TagName)
    @Html.Raw(" ")
}
```

Error message :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
> 'BlogWeb.Models.Post', but this dictionary requires a model item of
> type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BlogWeb.Models.Tag]'.

Comment: I'm not sure why the first one works, but IMO the last is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Define "working" and "not working".

Comment: @JeffMercado I included more data into question, in other hand it is just not inluding the Tags list into object. It stays empty

Comment: Your code looks off. The lines that start with dbContext are never assigned to a variable so they essentially do nothing. Highly recommend resharper...

Comment: Question was not about "how should i write my code" what I already know.   the question was why I do not even need variable in this example. Also resharper is useless with mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are chaining those Linq methods together you're building up a query behind the scenes. Adding `Include(...)` tells it to join the other data on before executing. When you call `ToList()` the Linq query is executed with the `Include(...)`.

On the second example, you are not executing a query so when you call `dbContext.Posts.ToList()` it hasn't cached anything and is a different query that is getting executed without the `Include(...)`.

Comment: But then why the second one is not working? I am casting ToList at the end and still with no succes, with your answere the include would be addin the query at the end and the ToList in return should be enough to execute this query which is at the end

Comment: Because this statement `dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags);` is never executed.

Comment: Oh! So ToList is here like Execute! I Got it, thank you

Comment: Yep, to reiterate a point from above, use the 3rd example in your actual system though not the 1st or 2nd.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags);` you are just creating a query. No elements are bring from database.

When you call `dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags).ToList();` you are creating the query and executing it. The elements are loaded into memory (including `Tags` property).

In your second example, when you execute `return View(dbContext.Posts.ToList());` no elements are in memory and you are not telling to include `Tags` when elements comes from database.

In your first example, you are not including `Tags`, but EF keeps tracks of elements previously loaded to avoid database queries, and this elements where loaded including `Tags`. Thats why results include `Tags` property.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that when working with Collections `ToList`, `ToArray`, `AsEnumerable` (I think thats all of them) all force EF to execute against the database and materialize the objects back to memory. In otherwords, if you dont iterate over the collection or call one of those then nothing happens.

> This one is working:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    BlogContext dbContext = new BlogContext();
    dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags).ToList();
    return View(dbContext.Posts.ToList());
}
```

EF tracks the state of entities internally. So line with code `dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags).ToList();` will retrieve all posts as well as the Tags for each post. When you then call `return View(dbContext.Posts.ToList());` the Tags have already been retrieved from the Database and, unless you added a new post in that fraction of a second, there wont be any issue.

> and this one is not:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    BlogContext dbContext = new BlogContext();
    dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags);
    return View(dbContext.Posts.ToList());
}
```

Line `dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags);` tells EF to include Tags but does not do anything else with it, you essentially just threw away the command you were working on. You then call `dbContext.Posts.ToList()` which retrieves just the posts. So now you have Posts but no included tags.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    BlogContext dbContext = new BlogContext();
    var model = dbContext.Posts.Include(a => a.Tags).ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

This is the  way to use EF as now you are not discarding your result on the `DbSet<t>`. All the EF extension commands materialize something and you are meant to use that result. The `DbSets<T>` themselves are not made to keep track of what was executed on them (with the exeption of EF entity tracking but that is not what I am talking about). DbSet is not a command object so you shuuld not use it as such.